# Can't run selenium Chromedriver (was working fine before)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

so today I went to run a program I made in python 3, but it kept crashing when it tried to open chromium. I haven't updated python or the chromedriver.exe so it was strange why it didn't work.

Current version of chrome driver I have installed: 74.0.3729.6

I have tried the following things but it didn't work:

1. Updating to the latest version of the chrome driver (v77.0.3865.10)
2. Downgrading to v73 of the chrome driver

Nothing has worked. Could someone please assist me.

---

I made this test program with just it launching the chrome browser:

**main.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.create_options()
driver.maximize_window()
```

---

crash message:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50904/devtools/browser/c1dc7138-e0cb-4ce4-a
561-56588f5ffd26
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not crea
ted: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57
e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of both Chrome (or Chromium) and Chromedriver must coincide.

As you can see in the error, your current Chromedriver only works with Chromium version 74.

Check the version of you Chromium and install the corresponding version of Chromedriver. To do this you can run the following command in a terminal.

```sh
apt-cache policy chromium
```

Comment: By this you mean version 74 of Chromium?

Comment: I have version 74.0.3729.6 installed of chrome driver and the support note says `Supports Chrome version 74`

Comment: The important one to check is the one for Chromium. The version of Chromium must coincide with the one for Chromium.

Comment: Yea, the support note says `Supports Chrome version 74` https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads . This literally worked 3 days ago and today it doesn't work. I haven't changed anything in the code or the chrome driver

Comment: I get that. But what is the version of your Chromium? Not the version of your Chromedriver

Comment: How do I check the version of Chronium? I can't even launch the browser in python

Comment: You could open it manually just to check the version or use a terminal to get the version, I'll update my answer with this as well.

Comment: I am using windows, not linux though. I don't have chromium installed either. It just launches from the chromedriver I guess.

Comment: Well, in your code you are actually using Chrome, so I would suggest you open your Chrome and check the version in it so that you can download the correct Chromedriver. Because of the constant updates in Chrome you may need to do this quite frequently for your code to keep working.

Comment: So instead of downgrading chrome, how can I update my code instead?

Comment: you need to update your chrome driver. Not the chrome version.